# Writing to a file duplicates the last entry

Tags: c++, filestreams

I think this is the only lines of code needed. The program reads from a text file, separates the information out and rewrites it to two different files. It "correctly" reads all the values, and separates it appropriately. the issue I am having, is in the files for output it duplicates the last entry to the file. I know how to solve this if I am using `getline()` for the input, but I am reading in each individual word separately in the file.

Here is the code for where I think the issue is:

```
while (in_file.peek() != EOF)
{
     in_file >> rank >> boy_name >> boy_number >> boy_percent >> girl_name >> girl_number >> girl_percent;
     boy_output << rank << " " << boy_name << " " << boy_percent << endl; 
     girl_output << rank << " " << girl_name << " " << girl_percent << endl;
}
```

I used `while (getline(in_file, line) && in_file.peek() != EOF)` in a similar program, but like I said I was reading the information in line by line, instead of the word seperation.

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the vibe as I keep researching that I need to read it in as a line, and then read that line as a stream to break it apart. I'm pretty sure that would work, but I'm curious why it's duplicating the final entry, and if there is a way to correct it with the current code.

Comment: You don't check if your inputs succeeded or not before writing them out again. So when they fail (because the file ended) you write them out again regardless. Moral: Always check if the read was a success before using the values.

Comment: Awesome makes sense. I was thinking the check was just if the file opened properly, but glad to a confirmation to lock the "moral" in. Thanks!

Comment: For those who come after, I simply included the first line of the while loop within an if statement for when it is reading in the values. If it successfully reads the values, THEN it writes the next two lines to the files. Not sure if it's the "proper" way, but it achieved what I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using -

```
while(1)
{
    if(in_file.peek() == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    in_file >> rank >> boy_name >> boy_number >> boy_percent >> girl_name >> girl_number >> girl_percent;
    boy_output << rank << " " << boy_name << " " << boy_percent << endl; 
    girl_output << rank << " " << girl_name << " " << girl_percent << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to correct your input loop is:

```
while (in_file >> rank >> boy_name >> boy_number >> boy_percent >> girl_name >> girl_number >> girl_percent)
{
     boy_output << rank << " " << boy_name << " " << boy_percent << endl; 
     girl_output << rank << " " << girl_name << " " << girl_percent << endl;
}
```

This will loop as long as the stream extraction succeeds. This correctly handles both EOF and mismatches between the input data and your variable types.